# Worksheet Object Cells Properties error referencing a range on another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, properties, reference

When trying to reference a range on another worksheet.

I get

> runtime error 1004 Application defined or object defined error.

I have a workbook with two sheets, for the sole purpose of figuring this out. I am trying to copy a range from sheet 2 while sheet 1 is active.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub rangecopy()

    'This works
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:C1").Copy 

    'This only works if sheet 2 is active
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 3)).Copy

End Sub
```

Many properties of the Worksheets object are showing the application or object defined error, including the value fields which would normally show an array.

Worksheets Object Item 2 ("Sheet2") Cells Properties from Watch window
[image]

These fields did not show errors yesterday, and I was able to reference cells from other sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add refer to worksheet in range definition:

```
Option Explicit

Sub rangecopy()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        .Range("A1:C1").Copy 'This works
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 3)).Copy ' <-- Try this
    End With
End Sub
```

Bye

Comment: This guy (me) has been in a code hole for a couple days. I need to take more breaks. Your answer got me to review my references in the monster workbook I was in and all seems to be working now. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad I was helpful, thanks for the feedback.